# Dedicated settings for VPN connection in macOS

Tags: terminal, network, vpn

My installation of macOS High Sierra doesn't treat VPN connection as separate connection with it's own settings. Namely, VPN connections don't have their separate tab in System Preferences → Network as for instance USB/Wi-Fi connections.

I would like to be able to set some persistent VPN network preferences e.g. DNS server, Router. Currently I have to put desired settings manually after I've connected to VPN and remove them later, as they are meaningless outside VPN.

Is it up to VPN client to create/not create dedicated tab in preferences, or it's macOS's privilege? Can I workaround this by changing VPN client or via some Terminal commands?

I know that usually VPN provider forces necessary settings for connection, but it's not my case alas.

Comment: What kind of VPN software are you using?

Comment: @nohillside Checkpoint Endpoint Security

Comment: @Vsevolod Star VPN makes a dedicated service in the said panel. I am not affiliated to it; just use it for Spotify login. Also, doesn't your client offer some settings? Please add a screenshot of side bar of System Preferences too.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii Thanks for your suggestion I will check Star VPN. Did you mean network preferences screen?